# Spring batch list if uten for processor, classifier and writer

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need to read from csv file, process and write to db.

Scenario is

I read a line of data, in this line i have 12 record. For every record i need to do a process(same process for all of them)
After this process every record go to a different table (so different writer - jdbc).
Can I use spring batch for this kind of process?

In my procesor I can take the line of data and convert to 12 record.

but what i need to do in my classifier (ClassifierCompositeItemWriter), do it need to accept list and return a list?

Not logic to do that

```
public class EventClassifier implements Classifier<SpecificEvent, ItemWriter<? super List<Event>>> {

    @Override
    public ItemWriter<SpecificEvent> classify(List<Event> events) {
    
        for(Event event : events){
            
            if (ReasonEnum.BANKRUP.getReason().equals(event.getScoreReason())) {
                return bankrupWriter;
            }

            if...
            

        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the number of records fixed or dynamic? ie will all lines have 12 records or it could be more or less than that? This is key to design a good solution to your requirement. `in my classifier (ClassifierCompositeItemWriter), do it need to accept list and return a list?`: The writer does not return anything, it only accepts a list of items. So yes, your writer should accept a list of records, classify them and write them to the corresponding tables.

Comment: always 12 records. do my example for the classifier are ok? every record could need a different writers.. that why i think a need a classifier

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of record types is fixed, and following the unix philosophy of making one thing do one thing and do it well, I would create a writer per type and register those writers as delegates in the classifier composite writer.

That's definitely better than dozens of if/else statements in the same writer. The reason is that the day you want to add a new writer for a new record type, you would only create a new writer for that type and register it in your composite instead of modifying the single writer by adding an additional if statement.

Comment: When i read one line, i get 12 records. In my processor I can convert the line in 12 records and fill a list. I already created a writer by type. My issue it's more about the classifier who need to get a list of item, I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: You need to find a way to flat map the list of lists into a single list before reaching the classifier. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve is feasible with the built-in `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`.

Comment: There is reader, processor, writer, classifier... where do you want to do this operation?